# Firefox won't play MP4 files from the server

Tags: server, firefox, video, mp4

I'm hosting mp4 videos on my university server and when I try to play them in Firefox, I get the following error "No video with supported format and MIME type found". I can play those videos on Chrome and Opera, so I though it may be Firefox issue, but the same videos hosted on my private VPS server works fine also on Firefox. What may be the reason?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if your server properly configured and sending right MIME type for video files you serve. For MP4 its generally video/mp4. 
As for "its works in Chrome" - Firefox is picky with mime types.